# Tabindex on javascript elements

Tags: javascript, html, tabindex

I have a side nav with dots (each of these dots on click scrolls to anchor down the page).

For accessibility purposes, I'd like users to be able to tab through the dots. I have set up a `<span>` element to wrap the anchors of each dot and the tabindex works fine, however..

I'd like the click event to be fired when they tab on the nav element. ie: If they tab to dot 2 it should imitate a click event so it takes them to that anchor.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think that you should be able to solve your problem by listening for the "focus" event on the dots and simulating a click on the dot when you receive it. There are several ways to do this, depending on what frameworks (if any) you are using. For example, if you are working with jQuery and the dots are identified by having the "dot" class:

```
$('.dot').focus(function(e) {
    e.target.click();
}
```

---

Here's a small test page that I put together - it seemed to work in both IE10 and Chrome:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleOnLoad() {
                var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
                    elems[i].onfocus = function(event) {
                        if (event.target) {
                            event.target.firstChild.firstChild.click();
                        }
                        else if (event.srcElement) {
                            event.srcElement.firstChild.firstChild.click();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="handleOnLoad()">
        <span class="focus" tabindex="1"><ul class="inactive" tag="scroller"><a href="#scroll1">Foo</a></ul></span>
        <span class="focus" tabindex="2"><ul class="inactive" tag="scroller"><a href="#scroll2">Bar</a></ul></span>
        <span class="focus" tabindex="3"><ul class="inactive" tag="scroller"><a href="#scroll3">Baz</a></ul></span>
        <span class="focus" tabindex="4"><ul class="inactive" tag="scroller"><a href="#scroll4">Ban</a></ul></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben I'll give this a short shortly.

Comment: Hey @Ben S. it didn't quite work :/ I have a `span` surrounding the anchor so that it can be tabbed to. My HTML is this `<span class="focus" tabindex="1"><ul class="inactive" tag="scroller"><a href="#scroll" style="opacity:0;">O</a></ul></span>` - so how can I set the click on the anchor within the `ul` when it focus is on the `span` that surrounds it?

Comment: It sounds like it should work if you change `e.target.click();` to `$('a', e.target).click();`. If you know you won't have any whitespace in your markup, `e.target.firstChild.firstChild.click();` should also work if you don't want to have to do another query.

Comment: I've added a little test page to my answer that shows a version of the solution in more detail. It seemed to work fine for me in IE10 and Chrome - are you seeing any JavaScript errors in the console or other things that might help determine what's going wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell, something about the way that JSFiddle works means that the `handleOnLoad()` function isn't being called, so it doesn't set up the `onfocus` handlers. If I add something to `handleOnLoad()` that should has a clearly visible effect, like modifying the names of the links, I don't see it happen, and when I inspect the contents of the frame with a debugger, the `onfocus` handlers don't see to be there. When I try it offline (i.e. a simple HTML file that I open in a browser), it seems to work.

Comment: Just tried it in a flat HTML file and still not working. Using Firefox. Are you able to upload a html demo? :/ sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32855/discussion-between-ben-s-and-dt-dtdg)